# Migrating a taxonomy's tags to the native category

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, customization, themes, templates

So, I've inherited a website that uses a custom taxonomy for no real reason, leaving the native 'category' taxonomy unused.

As the site is undergoing a redesign, I'm going to want to use some new plugins and a new theme. Many of which, rely on the native 'categories' for various things.

I'd like to migrate the tags in the existing custom taxonomy to the native, and I wonder if anyone can suggest how? I'm aware it'll need a little SQL surgery. Consider that the custom taxonomy is called `pp_eventcategory` and applies to all the custom post types in the system including the native post type.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you say "Native Categories" you mean you want to move all Custom Posts to `Posts` and use `Post Categories`, correct?

Comment: It's possible to do this via the API as well, but if you want a quick fix, I'm pretty sure there are a couple of plugins that can do this for you if you search the wordpress.org repository.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee sort of: I want to move all `CPTs` and `Posts` to use the default/native `Post categories` taxonomy, whilst keeping `CPTs`

Comment: So you want to have a Custom Post Type separate from Posts and you want that Custom Post Type to use Categories? I think what your looking for is [register_taxonomy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy)

Comment: I'm talking about migrating an existing site to use the default taxonomy, so posts of the default post type, and a few CPTs. I know how to `register_taxonomy` etc already, what I need to do is migrate the data over.